# How do I add sums per group in two-dimensional array using enumerable functions?

Tags: ruby, reduce, enumerable

I have a two-dimensional array as follows:

```
ary = [["a", 10],["a", 20],["b", 9],["b",7],["c",12]]
```

I want to sum the numeric values with the same key, building a hash like:

```
desired_result = {"a"=>30, "b"=>16, "c"=>12}
```

I can use a hash with a default (`0`) and a loop as follows:

```
rslt = Hash.new(0)
ary.each do |line|
  rslt[line[0]] += line[1]
end
```

But I want to avoid the loop and use enumeration functions. I came up with the following (quite ugly) expression:

```
rslt = ary.group_by {|a| a[0]}.map {|k,v| [k, v.map {|v| v[1]}.reduce(:+)]}.to_h
```

which is much harder to read than the loop-version.

Is there a way to do this more elegantly without a loop?

Comment: loop unavoidable

Comment: Your second version also loops over the array. If you claim it does not, then it is not clear in what sense you are using the word "loop".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) I'd suggest to chain [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values):

```
ary.group_by(&:first).transform_values { |v| v.sum(&:last) }
#=> {"a"=>30, "b"=>16, "c"=>12}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really like this one - concise and no necessity for either defaults or re-casting to hash. Did not know about transform values...

Answer (score 3):

You could use `each_with_object` (or `inject`) and pass in a hash where new keys get initialized with a value of zero:

```
ary.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){ |(k, v), count| count[k] += v }
# => {"a"=>30, "b"=>16, "c"=>12}
```

Comment: I suggest you edit to elaborate,"new keys get initialized with a value of zero" and provide a link to the doc for `Hash::new`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ary = [["a", 10],["a", 20],["b", 9],["b",7],["c",12]]

h=ary.group_by{|x|x[0]}.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
  h[k]=v.sum{|y|y[1]}
end
```

p h

```
{"a"=>30, "b"=>16, "c"=>12}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ary.group_by(&:first).map {|k, v| [k, v.sum(&:last)]}.to_h
```